# Calculate $\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(‎\sum_{m=1}^{t}‎\left(\frac{(\pi ‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\;‎\frac{1}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2t+2m-2}}\right)‎\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form

In my research I dealt to the following series. 
‎\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\Big(‎‎\sum_{m=1}^{t}‎\Big(\frac{(\pi ‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\;‎\frac{1}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2t+2m-2}}\Big)‎‎\Big)
\end{align*}
where ‎‎$‎\beta‎‎\simeq0.7‎$ ‎and ‎$\xi\in‎\mathbb{C}‎‎‎$.‎‎
‎

‎‎‎‎‎‎According some theorems I found that the limit exists.  I tried to find the limit by comparing my series with the well-known ‎series ‎as ‎follows:‎‎
‎\begin{align*}‎‎‎‎
\sum_{m=1}^{‎\infty‎}‎\frac{(\pi ‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}=‎\sinh‎(\pi \xi).
\end{align*}
But the second fraction made it hard. Also, I found that the second fraction is bounded above. But my favourite is to find  any well-known function or any closed form for my series. Can anyone help me. thanks. 
‎

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}‎‎\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{(\pi‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\frac1{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2n+2m-2}}‎‎\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(\pi‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\frac{[m\le n]}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2n+2m-2}}\\
\end{align}
$$
where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Note that for $\beta\lt2$
$$
0\le\frac{[m\le n]}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2n+2m-2}}\le\frac1{1-2^{\beta-2}}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{[m\le n]}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2n+2m-2}}=1
$$
Thus, by Dominated Convergence,
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(\pi‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\frac{[m\le n]}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2n+2m-2}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(\pi‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{[m\le n]}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2n+2m-2}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(\pi‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\\[3pt]
&=\sinh(\pi\xi)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: ♦, Firstly, thanks for your answer. Then my question is: what did you do from line 1 to 2 after "by Dominated convergence"? would you explain more why the limit goes across the series? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It might be easier to think of the series as

$$‎‎\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(\pi‎\xi‎)^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\cdot a_n(m),$$

where $a_n(m) = \frac1{1-2^{‎\beta‎-2n+2m-2}}‎, 1\le m \le n,$ $a_n(m)=0,m>n.$ Then the idea is to show there is a  constant $C$ such that $a_n(m)\le C$ for all $m,n,$ and furthermore for fixed $m,$ $a_n(m)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty.$ You're then set up for DCT.

Comment: @soodehMehboodi: If a series is dominated termwise by a convergent series, then the limit may be moved inside the summation. In this case, the dominating convergent series is $$ \frac1{1-2^{\beta-2}}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{|\pi‎\xi‎|^{2m-1}}{(2m-1)!} $$

Comment: @zhw: I think that is what I was trying to say. Hopefully, between the two explanations, the matter will be cleared up.

Comment: For sure, but  the bell was not quite ringing for our OP so I thought I would just slightly recast it.